# SharePoint Add Days to a Date Field Using C#

Tags: development, event-receivers

I am currently using an event receiver in a SharePoint site meant to onboard new employees. New user info is entered into a list called "New Hire Profile" and a second list called "Access Profile" is created based on the new hire profile list. There is a field on the employee profile called "Start Date" which is a simple SharePoint date content type. I am trying to create an calculated "Due Date" field in the access profile for tasks due on the start date. I would like to add the "StartDate" which is a date picker and "Dueindays" which is a numeric field listed on a third list "newHireTaskTemplate". The code is setup to pull the info from the fields and copy them to the new list. I am unsure how to go about adding days to the date picker date. My code currently looks like this:

```
accessProfile["Title"] = employeeProfile.ContentType.Name;
accessProfile["FirstName"] = employeeProfile["FirstName"];
accessProfile["LastName"] = employeeProfile["LastName"];
accessProfile["StartDate"] = employeeProfile["StartDate"];
accessProfile["DueDate"] = employeeProfile["StartDate"] + newHireTaskTemplate[DueinDays]???
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check the below Sample:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(employeeProfile["StartDate"].ToString());
int days=Convert.ToInt32(newHireTaskTemplate[DueinDays].ToString());
date.AddDays(days);


accessProfile["DueDate"] = date ;
accessProfile.Update();
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I assume the first line is missing an ")" `code` string date = Convert.ToDateTime(employeeProfile["StartDate"].ToString());`code` I get  error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: I have since tried `code` string date = Convert.ToDateTime(employeeProfile["StartDate"]).ToString();`code` which it seems to like. However in `code` date.AddDays(days); `code` it does not like .AddDays. I get "Error String does not contain a definition for "AddDays" and no extension method adddays accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found.

Comment: @initech yes you're right i wrote it right a way without IDE and didn't review it's my mistake, check the update